# Why does my state machine throws error: invalid transition?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, state-machine

I am trying to implement a state machine. The scenario is if a document is submitted then it is sent for review and after that approved.

But it throws an error that reviewed -> approve transition is invalid.

Here's the code that might give the better picture.

Why do it throw error? I hae made sure that everything is in order but still.

```
 public enum ProcessState
    {    
        Submitted,    
        Reviewed,    
        Approved    
    }  

    public enum Command
    {    
        Submit,    
        Review,    
        Approve    
    }   

    public class Process
    {    
        class StateTransition
        {
            readonly ProcessState CurrentState;    
            readonly Command Command;      

            public StateTransition(ProcessState currentState, Command command)
            {    
                CurrentState = currentState;    
                Command = command;    
            }   

            public override int GetHashCode()
            {    
                return 17 + 31 * CurrentState.GetHashCode() + 31 * Command.GetHashCode();    
            }    

            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {    
                StateTransition other = obj as StateTransition;    
                return other != null && this.CurrentState == other.CurrentState && this.Command == other.Command;    
            }    
        }    

        Dictionary<StateTransition, ProcessState> transitions;

        public ProcessState CurrentState { get; private set; }   

        public Process()
        {    
            CurrentState = ProcessState.Submitted;    
            transitions = new Dictionary<StateTransition, ProcessState>    
            {    
                 { new StateTransition(ProcessState.Submitted, Command.Review), ProcessState.Reviewed },

            { new StateTransition(ProcessState.Reviewed, Command.Approve), ProcessState.Approved },

            };    
        }   

        public ProcessState GetNext(Command command)
        {    
            StateTransition transition = new StateTransition(CurrentState, command);    
            ProcessState nextState;

            if (!transitions.TryGetValue(transition, out nextState))

                throw new Exception("Invalid transition: " + CurrentState + " -> " + command);

            return nextState;    
        }    

        public ProcessState MoveNext(Command command)
        {    
            CurrentState = GetNext(command);    
            return CurrentState;    
        }    
    }    

    public class Program
    {   
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            Process p = new Process();

            Console.WriteLine("Current State = " + p.CurrentState);    
            Console.WriteLine("Command.Submit: Current State = " + p.MoveNext(Command.Submit));    
            Console.WriteLine("Command.Review: Current State = " + p.MoveNext(Command.Review));    
            Console.WriteLine("Command.Approve: Current State = " + p.MoveNext(Command.Approve));    
            Console.ReadLine();  
        }    
    }
```

Update:

here is the error part:

```
  public ProcessState GetNext(Command command)
        {

            StateTransition transition = new StateTransition(CurrentState, command);

            ProcessState nextState;

            if (!transitions.TryGetValue(transition, out nextState))

                throw new Exception("Invalid transition: " + CurrentState + " -> " + command);

            return nextState;

        }
```

Comment: Attach a debugger. Walk execution and inspect state. The computer is correct- which expectations differ from those held? Remember to reduce the issue to an SSCCE for questions- many problems are identitied while doing this reduction.

Comment: @user2864740: i just did. check thanks

Comment: Of course that's the "error part", you are explicitly throwing an exception. Did you copy that code from some place? Have you tried debugging that code?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: not copied but took help its my own effort. i am debugging but i am very new to programming and implementing my automata lecture but can't.

Comment: Your `transitions` dictionary doesn't contain a single entry for `Command.Approve`.  So of course it's going to fail as expected.

Comment: @Zer0: i have changed that, check... but still error

Comment: now submitted -> submit error

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto: i meant that I have edited that part.

Answer (score 1):

This allows your example `Main` to run correctly.  The problem is your `transitions` dictionary had no entry for `Command.Approve`.

```
public Process()
{
    CurrentState = ProcessState.Submitted;
    transitions = new Dictionary<StateTransition, ProcessState>
    {
        //This does nothing.  Submitted -> Submitted
        { new StateTransition(ProcessState.Submitted, Command.Submit), ProcessState.Submitted },
        //Submitted -> Reviewed
        { new StateTransition(ProcessState.Submitted, Command.Review), ProcessState.Reviewed },
        //Reviewed -> Submitted.  Do you want this?
        { new StateTransition(ProcessState.Reviewed, Command.Submit), ProcessState.Submitted },
        //I added this.  Reviewed -> Approved
        { new StateTransition(ProcessState.Reviewed, Command.Approve), ProcessState.Approved }
    };
}
```

Outputs:

> Command.Submit: Current State = Submitted
>
> Command.Review: Current State = Reviewed
>
> Command.Approve: Current State = Approved

Note I did not check all your state machine transitions.  I merely added the missing one.

Comment: gosh, it's working but what you did there is beyond my understanding HAHA. Can you explain in layman terms?

Comment: @CodingManiac I did at the top of the answer.  Your state machine wasn't handling `Command.Approve` so I added it.  Whether all the other state transitions are allowed is up to you.  The one I added allows something to go from `ProcessState.Reviewed` to `ProcessState.Approved` using `Command.Approve`.

Comment: great but when i remove the first line, as u said it does nothing... then it throws error: submitted -> submit invalid exception

Comment: @CodingManiac That's because of the call to `MoveNext(Command.Submit)`.  That's not needed because the state is already `ProcessState.Submitted`.  It doesn't hurt anything to leave that first line in, but it doesn't do anything either.